# Quotient representation, in linear algebra and in topology

Tags: general-topology, representation-theory, quotient-spaces

A complex vector space $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$ can be split into classes so that two vectors belong to the same class if their difference lies in a subspace $\,{\mathbb{V}}_B\subset \mathbb V\,$. By choosing a representative $\,v\,$ in a class, we can present the class as $\,v+{\mathbb{V}}_B\,$, $\,v\in{\mathbb{V}}\,$. These classes constitute a complex vector space named *factor space* and denoted with ${\mathbb{V}}/{\mathbb{V}}_B$.

If a representation $A(G)$ of a group $G$ is acting in $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$, and its subrepresentation $B(G)$ is acting in $\,{\mathbb{V}}_B\,$, then in the factor space ${\mathbb{V}}/{\mathbb{V}}_B$ is acting a homomorphism
$$
 A/B\,:\;\;G\,\longrightarrow\,GL({\mathbb{V}}/{\mathbb{V}}_B)
 $$
$$
 (A/B)(g)\,(v\,+\,{\mathbb{V}}_B)\;\equiv\;A(g)\,v\;+\;{\mathbb{V}}_B
 $$
called *quotient representation*. Owing to the invariance of ${\mathbb{V}}_B$ under $A(G)$ or, equivalently, under $B(G)$, this definition is invariant under the choice of the representative $v$.

Now, suppose that $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$ is a *topological* vector space (TVS) equipped with a topology $\cal T$ and written down as $\,({\mathbb{V}},\,\cal T)\,$.

In this case, ${\mathbb{V}}_B$ also will be a TVS, in the induced-topology sense.

Also, suppose that ${\mathbb{V}}_B$ is closed in $\,({\mathbb{V}},\,\cal T)\,$. This makes $B(G)$ a subrepresentation not only in the algebraic but also in the topological sense.

QUESTION

Will the factor space $A/B$ be a topological space?

MORE SPECIFICALLY

Is it pointless to ask if ${\mathbb{V}}/{\mathbb{V}}_B$ is topological in the sense of $\cal T\,$?
$\,$Will the topology $\cal T$ of ${\mathbb{V}}$ naturally induce a quotient topology ${\cal{T}}^{\prime}$ in the factor space ${\mathbb{V}}/{\mathbb{V}}_B$, so that ${\mathbb{V}}/{\mathbb{V}}_B$ could become a TVS space $({\mathbb{V}}/{\mathbb{V}}_B\,,\;{\cal{T}}^{\prime})\,$?

Comment: Are you requiring group multiplication and inverses to be continuous maps? In general, the answer should be yes, just by declaring the finest topology such that open sets are those whose preimage is open. But do you want any structure to be passed on? Because $G$ doesn't seem to play a role here at all.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thank you for this good question. I used to think that a representation of a group in a topological space implies the continuity of the inverses and group multiplication. Please correct me if I am wrong. (I am a physicist, and my mathematical education is superficial.)

Comment: You have that $G$ acts on a vector space. You also have a topology on the vector space. The only requirement is that some subspace is closed and $G$-invariant. So what difference does it make if $G=1$?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I agree that $G$ is unimportant here. It emerged solely as a motivation to require ${\mathbb{V}}_B$ to be closed in $\mathbb V$.

Comment: In which case you only need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thank you for the link. Seems perfectly relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can always form a space with the so-called quotient topology.

In general, one can take a set $S$ and quotient by an equivalence relation $\sim \subseteq S^2$ to get a map and a set $\pi : S \to S / \sim$.

If $S$ has a topology, then $S / \sim$ can be given the quotient topology, where a set $U \subseteq S / \sim$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open. This topology makes $S / \sim$ into a topological space and $\pi : S \to S / \sim$ into a continuous map.

If we're dealing with vector space quotients, then we know the quotient map $\pi : \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V} / \mathbb{V}_B$ is a linear map. We can then topologise $\mathbb{V} / \mathbb{V}_B$ with the quotient topology. One can then prove that $\mathbb{V} / \mathbb{V}_B$ is a topological vector space under this topology and the induced vector space structure.

In fact, $\mathbb{V} / \mathbb{V}_B$ has the following property:

Let $f : \mathbb{V} \to U$ be a continuous linear map between topological vector spaces such that $\mathbb{V}_B \subseteq \ker f$. Then $f$ extends to a unique map $f' : \mathbb{V} / \mathbb{V}_B \to U$ such that $f' \circ \pi = f$; furthermore, $f'$ is a continuous linear map.

This is just piecing together the properties of quotient sets (which state that $f'$ exists), quotient vector spaces (which state that $f'$ is linear), and quotient topological spaces (which state that $f'$ is continuous).

In particular, consider a representation $A : G \to Hom_{TopVec}(\mathbb{V}, \mathbb{V})$ which takes an element of the group $G$ and outputs a continuous linear map $\mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$. In particular, let us assume that it restricts to a map $\mathbb{V}_B$ to $\mathbb{V}_B$.

Note that given $g \in G$, we see that the map $\pi \circ A_g$ has the property that $\mathbb{V}_B \subseteq \ker (\pi \circ A_g)$. Thus, this map extends to a unique continuous linear map $\mathbb{V}_B \to \mathbb{V}_B$. It's not hard to show that this results in a representation $A / B : G \to Hom_{TopVec}(\mathbb{V} / \mathbb{V}_B, \mathbb{V} / \mathbb{V}_B)$.

Note: if you require a topological vector space to be $T_1$ then you need $\mathbb{V}_B$ to be closed in order for the quotient space to be $T_1$.

I'm not sure what you mean when you ask whether $A / B$ itself is a topological space. I thought that $A / B$ was supposed to be a representation.

The last thing to note here is that we don't necessarily need the underlying field of our vector spaces to be $\mathbb{C}$. In fact, any topological field will do. If you'd prefer to work with a field that doesn't have a particularly special topology, you can topologise it with the discrete topology.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. A lot of food for thought.  My question on A/B  was unclear. It is indeed a representation. So the question was of course about the space $V/V_B$ where this rep is acting. I shall correct it now.

Comment: Mark, would it be right of me to say that, if $\mathbb V$ is Hausdorff then ${\mathbb{V}}_B$ must be closed in order for  ${\mathbb V}/{\mathbb{V}}_B$ to be Hausdorff?